# How do perform a system wide touch event with Android

Tags: java, android, touch

today I saw an App on Android which does not need root privilegues.
It records my touch input and repeats it as I wish. It was an auto-clicker App to automatically click in an other App.

I wonder how this is made. I want to create an own Android App with Java but I have no clue how this is made.

Do they work with an background task? With a Service? How does this App have the privileg to access my android system. Because it does not only work in its own App-Context.

I would like to achieve the same. An app which performs touch events at an exact position of my wish in another app.

Does anyone know how to realize this?

Comment: "I saw an App on Android which... records my touch input and repeats it as I wish" -- feel free to provide a link to it. For example, TeamViewer offers this, but that is only for certain device manufacturers, where TeamViewer has a deal to have access to proprietary APIs for this purpose.

Comment: there are plenty. e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.x0.strai.frep

Comment: "How does this App have the privileg to access my android system" -- it doesn't. It requires the use of root or Android SDK tools to give it the necessary privileges.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to start on myself with some auto-clicker or something else like this? I basically just want to tell my app: "Click there and there and there and there".

Comment: does anyone know some tutorial?